# PEP 8: library specific imports?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

According to PEP 8 guidelines, "library specific imports" should come last at the import list. But what does this exactly mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misread it, it says:

> "**local** application/library specific imports

where *local* applies to both application and library imports of your own (eg. your own libraries / classes).

Answer (score 4):

Imagine, you are developing a [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/)-application `myapp` that has modules `A` and `B`. And your code in `myapp.A` uses some functions from `myapp.B`. It also uses Twisted features and some built-in collections. That's how you structure your imports in `A.py`:

```
# Standard library imports first
from collections import defaultdict

# 3rd-party imports
from twisted.internet import reactor

# And now your own modules
from myapp.B import foo, bar
```